# Using embed.ly to only embed certain links

Tags: php, jquery, embed

I'm using embed.ly to embed links when a user types in [embed=LINK]. I'm using the jQuery embed.ly plugin.

I only want links that are tagged as embed, to be embedded:

For example if there are two links:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7aPGa9Gqj2c&feature=related
```

and

```
[embed=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7aPGa9Gqj2c&feature=related]
```

I only want the second link to be embedded,  and the first one to appear as a link.

I use the following code to find all Embed tags:

```
if (preg_match_all('/\[Embed=([^\]]+)\]/i', $input['body'], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) 
{
    $get_embedly = true;

    foreach ($matches as $match) 
    {
        if (preg_match($embedly_re, $match[1])) // $embedly_re = list of sites allowed
        {
            $input['body'] = str_replace($match[0], '> '. "<a href=\"$match[1]\">$match[1]</a>", $input['body']);
        }
    }   
}
```

I use jQuery and embedly in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/embedly/jquery.embedly.js"></script>
```

Do you have any suggestions as to how I should go about this? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are 98% of the way there. There are just a couple things you should add/change and you will be set.

Change line 9 of your PHP code to add a class `embedly`:

`$input['body'] = str_replace($match[0], '> '. "<a class=\"embedly\" href=\"$match[1]\">$match[1]</a>", $input['body']);`

Then use the class we just added to tell Embedly jQuery what `<a>` tags to embed.

`$('a.embedly').embedly(
         {maxWidth: 500,
          method: "replace"});`

Done.

Comment: lol, you're awesome,... did you sign up just to answer this? If so :)